# Coding and SNR gain

Tags: wireless, digital-communications

How does coding reduce the amount of SNR required to detect data for a certain modulation and at a certain bit error rate and does that imply that coding reduces noise power?

Comment: It depends on the coding. But you have probably been introduced to the idea that adding redundancy allows signal recovery in the presence of greater noise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How does coding reduce the amount of SNR required to detect data for a certain modulation  and at a certain bit error rate

This is basically asking for an introduction to channel coding theory; since that's out of scope, and would be better researched with a basic textbook / website than asking here, I'll just give a very condensed look on it:

Coding makes \$k\$ bits become \$n\$ bits, with \$n>k\$. This means there's *redundancy* added to the data. This means you will push fewer actual data bits through the channel in the same time!

But: It means that from this redundancy, you can correct error that were made due to noise. So, you can live with more noise.

So, while you *reduced* the rate of bits going through the channel, a well-chosen code will *increase* the rate of bits that go through *without error*.

> and does that imply that coding reduces noise power?

No.

Answer (score 1):

Noise is an unwanted part of the physical signal which is used to transfer the data bit stream along wires or radio path. A part of the noise cannot be avoided because it exists as a part of the behaviour of all materials. I mean thermal noise and some tricky random effect in semiconductors. The rest is caused by not so perfectly designed nor manufactured parts and circuits and as the unwanted output from other devices. Coding does not have any effect to the noise.

But coding can insert mathematical hints to the data stream. Those hints are used to reveal, that some bits are interpreted wrongly from the incoming signal and the software can calculate the most probable bit values which were actually sent in the transmitter. We call such codes "error correcting". As already said by others, such codings insert extra bits to the stream. The inserted bits add redundancy i.e. they are calculated from actual databits by using a predefined math rule, they are not random.

If the transferred data stream happens to be a digitized audio or video signal, the result of the error correcting coding is the reduction of apparent noise in the signal. Only that part of noise, which without error correction by coding would exist in the reproduced sound or video, is reduced. All defects present already in the original signal will stay.

Comment: this is a *nice* explanation! calling redundance *hints* is actually a good figure of speech, I'm going to adopt that, if I may, in the furture.

Comment: The term is free to be used.